# How to change zgrup field of customers with CMD_EI_API=>MAINTAIN_BAPI?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

In my ABAP report I need to change the `ZGRUP` field for many debitors (clients) at the same time. I wrote a report where it's updating the field using "update" but I won't get a protocol from that.

I found the class `CMD_EI_API=>MAINTAIN_BAPI` with this method but I don't know which fields I have to fill to update `ZGRUP`. Am I right using this method and if not is there an alternative?

Comment: `ZGRUP` you are writing how to update Z field. how do you think anybody would know the architecture of you app to know how to update this?

Comment: Isnt ZGRUP a standart field in KNB1?

Comment: @Suncatcher BWM3000 is correct. Even though it starts with Z, it's a standard field of table KNB1.